# need help if any one work with zkemkeeper class before vb.net or c#

Tags: vb.net

```
Public axCZKEM1,axCZKEM2 As New zkemkeeper.CZKEM


AddHandler axCZKEM1.OnAttTransactionEx, AddressOf Ax_OnAttTransactionEx
AddHandler axCZKEM2.OnAttTransactionEx, AddressOf Ax_OnAttTransactionEx




Private Sub Ax_OnAttTransactionEx(ByVal sEnrollNumber As String, ByVal iIsInValid As Integer, ByVal iAttState As Integer, ByVal iVerifyMethod As Integer, _
                  ByVal iYear As Integer, ByVal iMonth As Integer, ByVal iDay As Integer)

    lbRTShow.Items.Add("RTEvent OnAttTrasactionEx Has been Triggered,Verified OK")
    lbRTShow.Items.Add("...UserID:" & sEnrollNumber)
    lbRTShow.Items.Add("...isInvalid:" & iIsInValid.ToString())
    lbRTShow.Items.Add("...attState:" & iAttState.ToString())
    lbRTShow.Items.Add("...VerifyMethod:" & iVerifyMethod.ToString())

End Sub
```

this code for real-time Triggering fingerprint device

**First question**

How I know which device triggered this event : 
this device 'axCZKEM1' or 'axCZKEM2'

when I try put `'sender As Object'` with parameter give me error :

> "does not have signature compatible with delegate"

**Second question**

This code work fine in windows form but when put it in windows service the connection work but real-time trigging not work

Comment: just curious why are you using two same events and if i remember correctly you have to register an event with device id to make onAttTransaction work.

Comment: I make one event for two devices or more because this service connected to multi devices not just one

Comment: sorry to bother, but i think you can only able to connect to one device at a time right? using the ip address, ?

Comment: No, you can connect to more then one device ,  I made it before

Comment: its been a long time worked with zkem , are the device id are same?

Comment: if you mean IP every device has deferent IP

Comment: what is the version of your zkem,sdk

Answer (score 0):

I found answer for Second question

```
make Timer and put this code inside it

System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents()
```

but I still search for First Question